# Java Intellij - "Cannot resolve Symbol"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-error

When i compile/run my code, it functions perfectly. However, i have a persistent error message in my code stating that both `String` and `System` cannot be resolved.
As far as i can tell, it all seems fine, and like i said, it runs perfectly.
Has anyone got any ideas about what is causing this?

Thanks.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("This is main!");

        HelloWorld.helloWorld(); //I am calling the function "helloWorld" from the HelloWorld class
        System.out.println(ForLoop.loop()); //I am printing the return value of the function "loop" from the ForLoop class
        ReturnArgsLength.returnArgsLength(args.length); //Passing in variable to function

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with the code shown; add code from `HelloWorld`, `ForLoop` and `ReturnArgsLength` if you wish to debug it more

Comment: Listdown code of mentioned classes as well

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart, make sure JDK is configured correctly for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it.

The problem was that my .Class files were set in the File Types settings to "ignore".
Once i removed them from the list, it started recognising the commands again